# Using iAd as default ad network, and AdMob if iAd fails in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, admob, iad

I am looking to implement iAd as the default ad network and have AdMob fill in if iAd fails to fill the ad. I am wanting to do this in SpriteKit for both a banner ad at the bottom, and a video ad after the game ends. I am aware of the [Using iAd as default ad network, and AdMob if iAd fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3632032/using-iad-as-default-ad-network-and-admob-if-iad-fails) question but it is a little out dated, doesn't deal in in spritekit, and doesn't specify what frameworks to implement either.

Comment: you can incorporate iAd into your admob account with countless other services,  I would keep it simple and just use admob

Comment: iAd is know for much better return, just sometimes has poor fill rate, hence the use of AdMob to fill in the extra.

Comment: you get the same fill rate,  you are using the iAd service,  just through admob

Comment: with the admob api  you can specify the order of services that you want to use,  and admob will go though them till a fill happens

Comment: what is the point of using admob then if you are just using iAd through admob

Comment: I will look into that @Knight0fDragon thank you

Comment: you have all your ad services in 1 API, instead of having to handle multiple

Comment: Do you think it is worth using adMob as well or just iAd? My current app that uses only iAd has almost 100% fill rate but some say it struggles for them in other countries that maybe I have not had downloads. Is it better to just implement iAd and let it do its job rather than fussing with iAd and admob?

Comment: lot of countries still don't support iAd,  I just use admob like i said,  don't even bother with iAd API,  then depending  on region  i choose whatever networks work best,  USA I have set for iAd 1st google 2nd

Comment: So i added iAd. But AdMob Network was there to start with and says (optimized) right next to it not letting me change ECPM. I realize I can change the ECPM if I uncheck optimize. What ECPMs do you have iAd set at and AdMob set at so that iAd is first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a code project by a Stack Overflow user, crashoverride777, that will help you do just what you asked. It is very concise and helpful

https://github.com/crashoverride777/Swift-2-iAds-and-AdMob-Helper

If you want, look up the answer on this page 
[Show Admob Interstitial ads between scenes in Swift SpriteKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34452261/show-admob-interstitial-ads-between-scenes-in-swift-spritekit)